# WPF C# - problem with selecting options in DataGridComboBoxColumn controls

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding, datagrid

I have been learning WPF technology for several days. I have a problem with handling the DataGridComboBoxColumn control. Everything works fine, but after selecting an option from the selection list and moving to another row, the cell in which the value was selected has a red border and the entire control locks up without the possibility of further interaction.
Please help.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="colCategory"
                                        Header="Category" 
                                        IsReadOnly="False"
                                        Width="Auto" 
                                        MinWidth="150" 
                                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Category}" SelectedValuePath="Key"
                                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Category}" DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                                     >
```

And my pseudocode:

```
public class PairCategory
{
    public String Key { get; set; }
    public long ? Id { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryDescription : ObservableBase { public PairCategory Category { get => category; set => category = value; } }  

((DataGridComboBoxColumn)colCB.colObj).ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<PairCategory>(){ new PairCategory(..), .., PairCategory(..) }; this.controlDataGrid.ItemsSource = lstCategory;
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with combobox in datagrid. Probably locked for Binding. I used the following method for combobox

```
public void TestScenario()
{
     var exampleDataList = new List<ExampleData>();

     exampleDataList.Add(new ExampleData("UK"));
     exampleDataList.Add(new ExampleData("USA"));
     exampleDataList.Add(new ExampleData("France"));
     ExampleDataGrid.ItemsSource = exampleDataList;
}




public class ExampleData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   public ObservableCollection<string> countries { get; set; }
   public ObservableCollection<string> cities { get; set; }

   private string country;
   private string city;

   public string Country
   {
       get
       {
          return country;
       }
       set
       {
           country = value;
           // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
           OnPropertyChanged("Country");
       }
  }
  public string City
  {
      get
      {
          return city;
      }
      set
      {
          city = value;
      }
  }
      

  public ExampleData(string country)
  {
     this.country = country;
     countries = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "UK", "USA", "France" };
     cities = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "London", "Bristol", "Plymouth" };
  }

  // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
  {
      UpdateOptions();

     PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
     if (handler != null)
     {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

     }
  }

  public void UpdateOptions()
  {
      List<string> oldCities = cities.ToList<string>();
      List<string> newCities;

      foreach (string city in oldCities)
      {
          cities.Remove(city);
      }

      if (country == "UK")
      {
           newCities = new List<string>() { "London", "Bristol", "Birmingham" };
      }
      else if (country == "USA")
      {
           newCities = new List<string>() { "New York", "LA", "Texas" };
      }
      else if (country == "France")
      {
           newCities = new List<string>() { "Paris", "Lyon", "Nice" };
      }
      else
      {
          newCities = new List<string>();
      }

      foreach (string city in newCities)
      {
          cities.Add(city);
      }
   }
}
```

xaml code

```
   <DataGrid
    Name="ExampleDataGrid"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    >
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Country">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding countries}" SelectedItem="{Binding Country, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="city">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding cities}" SelectedItem="{Binding City, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```